# Moving an Image in Elliptical path

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation, android-imageview

I am in the process of creating an Android App which has an Image. The image has to circle around the center in the Elliptical path. I would require a function to return the X and Y coordinates of the Elliptical path. Could you please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below equations will give you x and y coordinates of ellipse.

```
x = a cos t 
y = b sin t
```

a - horizontal distance from origin.

b - vertical distance from origin

t - angle at which you need the coordinate.
[image]

```
List<Double> xcoord = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> ycoord = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void getCoordinates() {
    for(int i=0;i<360;i++) {
        xcoord.add(10 * Math.cos(i));
        ycoord.add(20 * Math.sin(i));
    }
}
```

The above function adds up all the coordinates from 0 to 360 to the list with 10 as horizontal distance from origin and 20 as vertical distance from origin. Hope this helps.

Comment: Mean time I got the same kinda solution. Thank you Buddy!. I have accepted your solution :)

Comment: @user1822729 what solution u got?

Comment: this answer is cool. but what if the axis' have an inclination? how to do then?

Comment: inclination? Didn't understand. Can you please explain

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/EllipticPictureTray/Pic_Tray_mechanics.png